# How to create this table in wpf? (Image inside)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

We need to create exactly this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXef9.jpg) table using WPF and XAML for a C# Application.
We would like to know if there a Table Creator in WPF that can Merge and Split Cells.

The number of rows is static, and the number of lines changes depending on the data that we have.

What is the best WPF tool to create this? And how?

Comment: have you tried anything yet ? if not start with wpf grid and datagrid, and show us the results. .

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Generally to avoid folks looking for someone to do their work for free you'll get asked "[what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)" to see an effort at least. That Grid structure isn't very complex and wouldn't be hard to do. If you drop a Grid on the designer view in Blend, you can point/click the rows/columns to generate your grid pretty easily also, but I strongly suggest that you learn how Grid works as you will need it more in the future if you're going to be using XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see the [MSDN article regarding tables in XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750416(v=vs.110).aspx). See the `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan` properties. It is quite a bit of work creating a table from scratch with XAML only, as I could not find a tool to automate this process, but this might be a start.

It is also possible to place controls in these tables. Just use `BlockUIContainer`.